# Ionic http promises does't assign object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

But after it this.account still being null

```
this.http.get(apiUrl, {}, headers) 
        .then(
          data => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.account = data.data
          this.pageError = '0'; 
              loadingPopup.dismiss();
            }, 1000);
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , Ionic http is an observable not a Promise. use subscribe instead of then

```
this.http.get(apiUrl, {}, headers) 
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.account = data.data
          this.pageError = '0'; 
              loadingPopup.dismiss();
            }, 1000);
          },
```